# Queue contents differ depending on where i access it from

Tags: c#, godot

I am currently coding a game using the Godot Engine 4.0.1, and now is the time to implement Attacks, Damage, and Knockback.

To apply knockback to the player, i have created the following method :

```cs
public void HandleOutsideForce(Godot.Vector3 force, bool enableRagdoll)
{
        AppliedForces.Enqueue(force / Mass);
}
```

Because i cannot edit the velocity outside of the PhysicsProcess function, and because this function is called when the player collides with a hitbox, i put the applied force inside of a queue, which i empty during the physics frame, like so :

```
public override void _PhysicsProcess(double delta)
    {
        base._PhysicsProcess(delta);
        ControlMethod.PhysicsProcess(delta); //You can disregard this part
        

        while (AppliedForces.Count > 0)
            Velocity += AppliedForces.Dequeue();
    }
```

However, after some testing, i have noticed that it doesn't work, as as soon as i try to access the Queue from the PhysicsProcess function, it is empty, while when i access it from the first function, it fills up normally.

Does anyone know why this might be happening ? Thanks in advance

Comment: No idea. Although, since you are going to add the values anyway, consider accumulate them them into a vector instead of adding them to a queue. I also find odd that you say you cannot access `velocity`. So a couple questions: Are you using another thread to enqueue the values? What is the physics body type (character body, rigid body…)? Addendum: For a character body you should be able to access `velocity`, for a rigid body you would use `ApplyImpulse`.

Comment: Yeah, actually the reason i used a queue at first is because i used to pass functions to be executed in the physicsprocess function that way, and i just started refactoring that. Also, i'm using a CharacterBody3D, and i'm not using threads or anything. It's not that i can't access velocity, but rather that im getting an error because i "tried to access a deferred value" or something along those lines

Addendum : the function on top is called when my player collides with an enemy hitbox

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out, i have no idea why it did this, no reasonable solution (such as CallDeferred, or SetDeferred) have worked, but i DID fix it by rewriting the file line by line, and testing each time, expecting to find a culprit.

NOTHING changed in the script yet it now works. Wonderful

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Since the code is running as part of the physics resolution (a collision) it cannot modify some physics properties (in this case `velocity`), and Godot will tell you use a deferred operation (i.e. `call_deferred` or `set_deferred`).

That leads you to a solution: From the collision use `CallDeferred` to call the method that will modify `velocity`. The deferred call will happen between frames, and outside of the physics process. Then there you should be able to modify `velocity` normally.

*I'm suggesting to use `CallDeferred` and not `SetDeferred` for correctness. I don't expect `SetDeferred` to cause an [ABA problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem), but I rather be sure.*

---

The other idea (which I suggested in comments) is to have a vector to accumulate the change of velocity you will apply in `_PhysicsProcess`.

---

*I'm not sure why the queue causes problem. I'm guessing it is a combination of the nature of .NET collections and Godot internal threading. Regardless, hopefully you can workaround it.*

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions ! However, when i use CallDeferred to edit the Velocity, i get the following error : System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.

And when i try to use an external vector as an accumulator, it seems like the modifications i do inside the first function only register in that code block, as when i access it from the physics function, the vector is still zero